# Matching regex, but not in comment without removing the comments

Tags: python, regex

In this line of code:

```
for iters in len(array) # for iters in len(array)
    for iters in len(array)
```

I'm trying to match both `for` and `in`, but outside the comment.

Tried using this regex `(?<!#.)(\bfor\b|\bin\b)` but it results in matching:

```
*for* iters *in* len(array) # for iters *in* len(array)
    *for* iters *in* len(array)
```

It also matches the `in` inside the comment. And currently have no idea how I can avoid the `in` inside the comment.

Saw another solution in here, but that involved removing the comment, which is not applicable in this case...

Comment: What language? Could use `#.*(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\b(for|in)\b` https://regex101.com/r/Fj3U2X/1

Comment: It's in python. Edited tag to specify :)

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is to split any line at '#' and match only on the first part, however you then need to ensure that you don't have any '#' inside of strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can [use this](https://regex101.com/r/AFaHWa/1) if you simply need to test whether the line matches:

```
^[^#]*(\bfor\b|\bin\b)
```

If you need each occurrence of for and in, try [something like this](https://regex101.com/r/L0oMGK/1):

```
(?:^|\G)[^#]*?(\bfor\b|\bin\b)
```

`(?:^|\G)` ensures that from the start of the line, or where the previous match left off, there are no `#` characters.

Answer (score -1):

Using a non-capturing group for handling comments it works.

Thus:
`(\bfor\b|\bin\b)|(?:#.*)` Will first match the `for`/`in` everywhere, and then the non-capturing group will match with the comments and ignore those.